# Java 8 Timer to repeat one function

Tags: java, timer, countdowntimer

How can I implement a timer in Java 8? I prefer one simple method for this. I want to do something every 15 min or 30 min. Any idea?

Comment: You mean like [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%208%20timer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
Thread.sleep(milliseconds)
```

call the function you want and put it inside Runnable .

Example :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000); // 3 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 //your Function
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

OR

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    // stuff here
}});
t.start();
```